# Bootstrap Popover Width and jQuery OnFocus

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input field that I want to show a popover for onfocus...

```
<input class="form-control popover_onfocus" type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" value="<?php if (!$form_valid && !empty($_POST)){ echo $username;} ?>" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Your student can login with this or his/her email address if you provide one." required autofocus>
```

Then here's the jQuery that makes it show up onfocus...

```
$('.popover_onfocus').popover({
    trigger: "focus"
});
```

I'd like to make this popover wider without changing all popovers in the bootstrap css file.  I've looked at other solutions and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You should be able to chain a .css() call onto the popover function.

Comment: @TiesonT.: I'm not fully sure how to do that.  Something like this?  $('.popover_onfocus').popover({
    trigger: "focus"
}).css('background', 'blue');

Comment: Yep. I'm not somewhere where I can type out an example, or I would, but you have the right idea. You could also define your own class and use addClass instead.

Comment: The problem is that this sets the css for the <input>, not the popover.

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking about how I typically tweak the modal styles, but that is also modifying the element on which it's called. What version of Bootstrap are you working with?

Comment: Seems to be v3.3.7

Comment: You can verify that by adding something like this in your script: `console.log($.fn.popover.Constructor.VERSION)`, if you're not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Bootstrap 4-Beta version

I won't pretend this is optimal, but if you don't want to go the template route, [this seems to work (jsFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/5ua15n21/1/):

#### Triggering button

```
<input class="form-control popover_onfocus" 
       type="text" 
       name="username" 
       id="username" 
       placeholder="Username" 
       value="" 
       data-toggle="popover" 
       data-placement="top" 
       data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" required autofocus />
```

#### Javascript

```
$('.popover_onfocus').popover({
    trigger: 'focus'
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('body .popover').css({ 'max-width': '800px' });
});
```

In this example, I'm overriding the max-width rule, but obviously you can change that to whatever you're trying to accomplish.

This seems to only work with `shown.bs.popover`, which makes sense; there's no generated markup to style until `show.bs.popover` has resolved.

Adding a `.popover('update')` *seems* to fix the position bug: https://jsfiddle.net/5ua15n21/2/

```
$('.popover_onfocus').popover({
    trigger: 'focus'
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
    $('body .popover').css({ 'max-width': '800px' }).popover('update');
});
```

---

### Bootstrap 3 Version

Bootstrap 3 doesn't work quite the same (probably due at least in part because they use an external library, Popper.js, for Bootstrap 4), so the above won't work. Here's a Bootstrap 3 version that uses the template option and a custom class:

#### Template

```
<script type="text/template" id="popover-template">
<div class="popover popover-wide"> <div class="arrow"></div> <h3 class="popover-title"></h3> <div class="popover-content"></div> </div>
</script>
```

#### Markup

```
<input class="form-control popover_onfocus" 
       type="text" 
       name="username" 
       id="username" 
       placeholder="Username" 
       value="" 
       data-toggle="popover" 
       data-placement="bottom" 
       data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right? And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?" required autofocus />
```

#### CSS

```
.popover.popover-wide
{
  max-width: 800px;
}
```

#### Script

```
$('.popover_onfocus').popover({
    trigger: 'focus',
    template: $('#popover-template').html()
});
```

I did slightly tweak your options, since the jsFiddle iframes don't seem to work quite right with the `top` position: https://jsfiddle.net/5ua15n21/3/

@DanielSixl's answer would work if you were using Bootstrap 4, but the markup for popovers is a little different in Bootstrap 3. I also prefer to use a template script tag, but you could hard-code the string instead.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work well on the first time of focusing on an `<input>`, but on subsequent times, it works perfectly.  Have any ideas on that odd behavior?  This is happening in your fiddle too.

Comment: I assume it's because the popover calculates it's position based on the normal styles it has before the override above. On subsequent calls, the popover has a greater width, so it positions itself correctly. That's one of the problems with using `shown.bs.popover`, but I'm not sure how you would accomplish it otherwise.

Comment: @gtilflm See edit. Looking at the docs for 3.3.7, the update option doesn't exist, though, so I'll probably need to figure out how to make the same work (the jsFiddle uses 4.0.0-beta)

Comment: I've been fiddling with adding `$('.popover_onfocus').popover("show");` then `$('.popover_onfocus').popover("hide");` before your code to try to get it to reveal the width, then close.  But it doesn't seem to be working.  Seems like kind of a hack too.....

Comment: @gtilflm I've added an optional implementation, if you want to give that a try.

Comment: Thanks for your continued help.  I just ended up doing `<style type="text/css">
        .popover{
            max-width:100% !important;
        }
    </style>` which seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Use a template variation with an additional class:

```
$('.popover_onfocus_variation').popover({
    trigger: "focus",
    template: '<div class="popover popover--variation" role="tooltip"><div class="arrow"></div><h3 class="popover-header"></h3><div class="popover-body"></div></div>'
});
```

With this class you can have a popover with a variation. For example doubled width. You will have to use `max-width` here:

```
.popover--variation {
   max-width: 512px;
}
```

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/LzLwKx?editors=1111

Comment: I don't know why, but this isn't working in my installation.  I see it's working on your codepen though.